# Merging 2 audios files with a video in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge 2 audio files (`.wav` with video file `.mp4`) to produce the output in `video.mp4` extension using ffmpeg on `Windows CMD`.

This is what I have tried :

```
ffmpeg -i V.MP4 -i A1.WAV -i A2.WAV -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -c:v copy -vcodec copy Output.MP4
```

The `CMD` output for that is :

[image]

This command will output the `Output.mp4` file but it will merge the video with only 1 of the audio files which is `A2.wav` and ignores the other audio file `A1.wav`

I want to merge without re-encoding or any offset, just merging the 3 files as they are in a file one `.mp4` file.

I checked some topics here in stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128438/2-source-videos-in-ffmpeg-how-to-map-audio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176141/ffmpeg-2-audio-files-in-one-video-file) but they didn't help.

Comment: Both audio files are present in the output. I assume you want a mixdown i.e. both should be heard at once?

Comment: Yes, that is right!!, but... isn't that what this command should do? Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to mixdown the audio, you should use the amix filter

```
ffmpeg -i V.MP4 -i A1.WAV -i A2.WAV -filter_complex "[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy Output.MP4
```

Comment: @Gyan How can i ajuste the volume of A1 and A2 ?

Comment: `"[1]volume=0.5[a1];[2]volume=0.2[a2];[a1][a2]amix=inputs=2[a]"`