# Using ffmpeg to merge two audio file and one video file with control volume?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to merge 2 audio files with one video file to create one video file, but in audio file I want to control the volume level of each file.

What should I do ?

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3
-filter_complex "[1]volume=0.5,pan=2c[a];[2]volume=0.7,pan=2c[b];[a][b]amix=duration=shortest"
-ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame -q:v 0 output.mp4
```

Comment: so you will have kind of 3 audio files, one from the video too. What I did is merge the audio files separately and then add it to the video file.

Comment: I learned about how to change the volume of a merge 2 audio file and how to merge 2 audio files with the video file and create the above formula, however, there was an error while executing.

Comment: My video file has no audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did that.
First merging the input audio files using the below method.

```
private fun mergeAudios() {
    //ffmpeg -i one.mp3 -i two.mp3 -shortest -filter_complex \
    //"[0:a]adelay=10000|10000,volume=0.4[a0]; \
    // [1:a]volume=5.0[a1]; \
    // [a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[out]" \
    // -map "[out]" -ac 2 -c:a libfdk_aac output.m4a
    val finalAudio =
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp3")
    val command = arrayOf(
        "-i",
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/2.mp3",
        "-i",
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/1543575307959.mp3",
        "-shortest",
        "-filter_complex",
        "[0:a]volume=0.4[a0];[1:a]volume=5.0[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest",
        finalAudio.absolutePath
    )
    Log.d("ffmpeg", command.contentDeepToString())

    ffmpeg.execute(command, object : ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        override fun onFinish() {
            super.onFinish()
        }

        override fun onSuccess(message: String?) {
            super.onSuccess(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "onSuccess ")

        }

        override fun onFailure(message: String?) {
            super.onFailure(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "failure " + message)

        }

        override fun onProgress(message: String?) {
            super.onProgress(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "progress " + message)

        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
        }
    })

}
```

And then merging the merged audio file with the video file.

```
private fun mergeAudioVideo() {
    val finalVideo =
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4")
    //ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav \
    //-c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental \
    //-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
    val command = arrayOf(
        "-i",
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/2.mp4",
        "-i",
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/1543577399776.mp3"
        ,
        "-c:v",
        "copy",
        "-c:a",
        "aac",
        "-strict",
        "experimental",
        "-map",
        "0:v:0",
        "-map",
        "1:a:0",
        finalVideo.absolutePath
    )
    ffmpeg.execute(command, object : ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        override fun onFinish() {
            super.onFinish()
        }

        override fun onSuccess(message: String?) {
            super.onSuccess(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "onSuccess ")

        }

        override fun onFailure(message: String?) {
            super.onFailure(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "failure " + message)

        }

        override fun onProgress(message: String?) {
            super.onProgress(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "progress " + message)

        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
        }
    })


}
```

Try this if it works for you. You might need some additional flags as your video has no audio files. If the command in the method doesn't work for you, try removing the `-map` argument for the audio flag

For a single command, this might work. I don't have the complete project to test it now so can't confirm for this one.

```
fun mergeAudioVideoDirectly(){
    val finalVideo =
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4")
    //ffmpeg -i <input1> -i <input2> -filter_complex "[0:a:0][1:a:0]amix[outa]" -map "[0:v:0]" -map ["outa"] <output>
    val command = arrayOf(
        "-i",
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/2.mp4",
        "-i",
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/1.mp3",
        "-filter_complex",
        "[0:a:0][1:a:0]amix[outa]",
        "-map",
        "0:v:0",
        "-map",
        "[outa]",
        finalVideo.absolutePath
    )
    Log.d("ffmpeg ","command "+command.contentDeepToString())
    ffmpeg.execute(command, object : ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        override fun onFinish() {
            super.onFinish()
        }

        override fun onSuccess(message: String?) {
            super.onSuccess(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "onSuccess ")

        }

        override fun onFailure(message: String?) {
            super.onFailure(message)
            Log.d("ffmpeg", "failure " + message)

        }

        override fun onProgress(message: String?) {
            super.onProgress(message)
        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168993/merging-2-audios-files-with-a-video-in-ffmpeg. As your solution, We can combine it into one command ?

Comment: @phongvan added one more method for merging directly. But I am not sure if this will work or not

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below command to mix audio video and volume setting

```
fun videoMixWithAudio(isNeedAudioCropped: Boolean): Array<String?> {
        val cmdList = ArrayList<String>()
        var cmds: Array<String?>? = null
        try {
            cmdList.add("-y")
            cmdList.add("-ss")
            cmdList.add(startVideoDuration.toString())
            cmdList.add("-t")
            cmdList.add(endVideoDuration.toString())
            cmdList.add("-i")
            cmdList.add(videoPath)
            cmdList.add("-ss")
            if (!isNeedAudioCropped) {
                cmdList.add("0")
            } else {
                cmdList.add(startAudioDuration.toString())
            }
            cmdList.add("-t")
            cmdList.add(endVideoDuration.toString())

            cmdList.add("-stream_loop")
            cmdList.add("-1")

            cmdList.add("-i")
            cmdList.add(audioPath)

            if (videovolume == -1f && audiovolume > -1) {
                cmdList.add("-c:v")
                if (startVideoDuration > 0) {
                    cmdList.add("mpeg4")
                    cmdList.add("-b:v")
                    cmdList.add("2304000")
                } else {
                    cmdList.add("copy")
                }
                cmdList.add("-c:a")
                cmdList.add("aac")
                cmdList.add("-map")
                cmdList.add("1:a:0")
                cmdList.add("-map")
                cmdList.add("0:v:0")
                cmdList.add("-strict")
                cmdList.add("-2")
                if (audiovolume < 0.99 || audiovolume > 1.01) {
                    cmdList.add("-vol")
                    cmdList.add((audiovolume * 100).toInt().toString())
                }
            }else{
                cmdList.add("-c:v")
                if (startVideoDuration > 0) {
                    cmdList.add("mpeg4")
                    cmdList.add("-b:v")
                    cmdList.add("2304000")
                } else {
                    cmdList.add("copy")
                }
                cmdList.add("-map")
                cmdList.add("0:v:0")
                cmdList.add("-strict")
                cmdList.add("-2")
                cmdList.add("-filter_complex")
                cmdList.add(
                    String.format(
                        "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=%f[a0];" +
                                "[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=%f[a1];" +
                                "[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first[aout]",
                        videovolume,
                        audiovolume
                    )
                )
                cmdList.add("-map")
                cmdList.add("[aout]")
            }

            cmdList.add("-b:a")
            cmdList.add("128000")
            cmdList.add("-ac")
            cmdList.add("2")
            cmdList.add("-ar")
            cmdList.add("44100")
            cmdList.add("-movflags")
            cmdList.add("faststart")
            cmdList.add("-preset")
            cmdList.add("ultrafast")
            cmdList.add(outputpath)

            cmds = arrayOfNulls<String>(cmdList.size)
            cmdList.toArray(cmds)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return cmds!!
    }
```